# Does the PUT command called using SnowSQL cause the data to egress private link?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-private-link

We have Azure Private Link setup for Snowflake but our network team noticed that when a PUT command is issued to upload a file to an internal named stage in Snowflake, it creates an HTTP request to xxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net.

Does this indicate that the data is leaving the private link and into the internet when uploading files?

Appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: Where are you running the PUT command from? A local PC, a VM (and, if so, where is the VM running)?

Comment: I run the PUT command from a server that is in our network & has SnowSQL. The connection string uses `-h xxxx.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com`. But the SnowSQl log shows this - `2021-01-21 20:25 (16736/Thread-5) botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool INFO connectionpool:735  - Starting new HTTPS connection (22):xxxx.blob.core.windows.net
2021-01-21 20:25 (16736/Thread-1) snowflake.connector.chunk_downloader DEBUG chunk_downloader:196  - chunk 1/1 is NOT ready to consume in 160/3600(s)` Does this mean the file upload happens outside privatelink?

Comment: Hi  - just checking but when you say "from a server that is in our network", do you mean that server is within your Azure Virtual Network? If it isn't then obviously its not going to use privatelink